# Angularjs one time binding is called twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why is the one time binding called twice?

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.foo = function() {
        console.log('foo'); 
        return 'foo';
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <span ng-bind="::foo()"></span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The same is for the regular binding (during first digest).

Comment: One time binding doesn't mean the function won't be evaluated every digest. If you don't want it called then run it in controller once and set a variable to pass to view instead

Comment: Agree with you. I can be replaced with preliminary initialization. But it is not useful from general perspective if there are a lot of one time binding depend on some logic.

Comment: Ok but what problem does it create?

Comment: It's about performance

Comment: The performance gain comes from less watchers. You can't control how internals handle the digests

Comment: Agree. But the answer would be some explanation why the angular core needs to call one time binding twice. I have not found the answer.

Comment: Every digest cycle runs a minimum of 2 digests and possibly more until the scope is stable

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue in angular core, read [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11416) post where they have a detailed discussion on this issue, They have explained one time bindings are not the way we think, expression evaluation can be called multiple times.

Answer (score -1):

The binding function will be called at every digest even if it is one time binding. If you want to avoid this then use NgInit to call function once.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.foo = function() {
        console.log('foo'); 
        return 'foo';
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <span ng-init="::foo()"></span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The binding function will not be called at every digest if it is one time binding.